# How can I specify the HADOOP_HOME after I install hadoop 1.0.1 in ubuntu with deb intall file

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, debian, debian-based

I have installed hadoop 1.0.1 in my ubuntu laptop by a deb install file.
the hadoop files are install into different directories, eg: config file are installed into /etc/hadoop, but the bin files are installed into /usr/sbin. So how can I specifiy the HADOOP_HOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HADOOP_HOME is the parent directory of the bin directory that holds the Hadoop scripts. [see Getting started with Hadoop](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop)

Answer (score 1):

I would not set HADOOP_HOME in this case. I am using 1.0.4 deb installation on Ubuntu as well, and the only ***HOME** I set is **JAVA_HOME** in `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`